# Unselecting and reselecting accepted answers allows gaming of Mortarboard badge

Tags: discussion, answers, badges, daily-reputation-badges, gaming-the-system

I was just looking over some of my old questions from a long time ago.  I wasn't sure if I was able to change answers on old questions (I know you can't change votes, after a grace period).  To test, I simply unselected and reselected the answer I had chosen.

This doesn't change my total reputation, but DOES assign +2 to my rep for today.  Surely this is a bug, no?

If I had 100 questions, I could easily rack up 200 rep to gain the Mortarboard badge (if I didn't already have it) by simply unselecting and reselecting answers.  Heck, if I were dedicated enough, I could do this every day to get the Epic and Legendary badges.  Imagine-- getting those badges with a total rep of only 200?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you lose enough reputation gain from an old day, you lose the "reputation cap hit" for that day. Happens a lot to people who see the loss of votes from deletion. It's not free rep, it's gotta come from somewhere, and in this case it's a matter of coming from *history* rather than any other source.

Yes, you could theoretically game this for Mortarboard somewhat easily, but nothing else as your reputation gains wouldn't be persistent. You'd need at least 5000 questions in order to try and game for Epic by accepts alone, and with a limit of 50 questions per month, you need *100 months* to reach that many. That's... not gaming. That's just a waste of your own time.

Comment: And a scant 15,000 questions for Legendary!

Comment: And for reference, the infamous asker "Blankman" is only a little over a quarter of the way to the 5,000 question mark as of right now: http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman

Comment: Still, it should not be possible to game the mortarboard badge, right?  Or re-arrange rep?  You don't necessarily need 5000 questions, I can simply re-select one or two questions if I'm a few points shy of 200.

Comment: @Jeff: And then a moderator will come along, recalc your reputation, and you'll be back where you were (one accept per question).

Comment: @Robert I don't understand...  Your rep is still calculated accurately (one accept per question), so that's not the issue.  It's a matter of re-arranging your rep to game the Mortarboard badge.

Comment: @Jeff he's talking about gaming Epic/Legendary.  You'd have to have 50/150 separate buckets of 100 questions to use per day because otherwise you'd be undoing one of your other days.  Those badges look across the lifetime of an account, and you don't get awarded multiple Mortarboard badges for hitting 200 on multiple days unless you are *still at* 200 for those prior days as well.

Comment: @Daniel yes, that was just a secondary comment.  thanks for the title fix...