# Revoked mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, badges, revoked-badges

On May 30, 2011, I earned the Mortarboard badge. [You can see it on my profile using the WayBack Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120524061342/https://stackoverflow.com/users/353278/jeff). (I also commented on it in a [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93341/162890) the day after I earned the badge.)

I am wondering why this badge would be revoked, as I've read several times that badges are never revoked.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 12/1:** A little over a week after I posted this question on meta, a rep change occurred. Apparently, this question that I answered on May 30 was deleted:

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/1F1y1L2u2D0u3X2H2S0k/so.png]

This is confusing for several reasons. First, the rep change occurred over a week after this question was posted. Furthermore, that question had several upvoted answers, including an accepted one, as you can see from this [cached version on Google](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MyIcip5N5pgJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/6171939/non-flash-interactive-map+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). I was under the impression that questions with upvoted answers could not be deleted. According to Google, the page was cached Nov 24--two days after I asked this question--and you can see my rep is at 2,338. So this is not a case of an answer that was deleted long ago and never reflected in my rep history. This may be a coincidence, but if so the timing is very odd...

In addition, I had commented (below) that my /reputation page indicated I had gotten 200 rep on at least one day. Now this has changed. It says:

```
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
```

But the figures above are still accurate-- in my time line, it still shows 200 rep on May 30.

Comment: Do you mind checking the [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page? Scroll down to the bottom and look for "earned at least 200 reputation on *x* days" and see if *x* is 1.

Comment: indeed it is: **earned at least 200 reputation on 1 days**

Comment: That's weird indeed. First I thought that it's some answer from that day "deaccepted" and then accepted again - but it seems not to be the case.

Comment: If you dare, there's also a button "Trigger Reputation Recalc" on that reputation page. In theory, that should not change anything, but you never know if things change for better or worse. And, according to that report, how much rep did you gain on May 30?

Comment: Turns out it's an old time bug, now fixed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's back! thanks Sha! also, my question being marked a duplicate of one that was posted 4 months later also sounds like a time bug ;]

Comment: Cheers Jeff glad to be involved in fixing this. As for dupe, ideally that other question would have been closed as dupe of yours but the official answer is already there.

Answer (score 11):

Comparing your reputation gained on that day with the current [description of the Mortarboard badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), I suspect it is because 2 of those 200 reputation points came from a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/281733) that was accepted. Or it might be because the description now says, "Earned **more than 200** reputation in a single day" while before it said ">= 200."

I am a bit surprised, though, since I read that badges—with the exception of tag badges—are not usually revoked when the criteria for earning the badge are no longer met (and as far as I gathered, the criteria for Mortarboard changed over time); they are removed only when they were obtained by fraudulent means (or erroneously, as earlier this year, when there was a mass awarding of Vox Populi due to a software glitch).

Comment: Where does it say "more than"? I see "at least"... Also, suggested edits count towards the daily reputation cap, and this badge.

Comment: [In the description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) in the faq here it says "more than". It wouldn't be the first time that the description on the badges page isn't what is implemented. But I don't _know_ what's going on, I'm just putting together the pieces of the puzzle I could find.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it *used* to be more than and it was changed along with everything else as that badge has been modified over time. I think that FAQ is just severely outdated.

Comment: Possibly. But it's still edited and updated a lot.

Comment: No, it's given for exactly 200 just fine, see [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1597833/themilkman?tab=activity&sort=badges) for example he got the badge on Nov 14 when he first got exactly 200 reputation. Smells like a glitch in the system, where's Nick when we need him? ;)

Comment: FWIW, I've updated the FAQ for Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary to reflect the [more accurate information provided by Nick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526).