# Show warning if bounty will make you lose privileges

Tags: feature-request, bounties, privileges

If you place a bounty that causes your rep to decrease below some privilege threshold, you lose those privileges. (See: [Is losing privileges after placing bounty OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/is-losing-privileges-after-placing-bounty-ok))

In such cases, I think a courtesy message should be displayed:

> **Caution: This bounty will result in a loss of [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges)**

I have lost privileges on meta.SO for this reason after offering +500 bounty on my question. I am not complaining, or asking for those privileges back. However I believe most people, like myself, are unaware of this. Frankly, I would have offered the bounty anyway, because I really wanted my question answered (though it remains [unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156422/revoked-mortarboard-badge)).

I think it is common courtesty to inform people of the effects of their actions, particularly in this case where such effects are not implied.

Comment: [It informs you of this in the privileges link.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)  I don't disagree that such a message should be slightly more noticeable, but it isn't entirely like you're getting hoodwinked, if you know what privilege you're invoking.